# Native client or what?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have some c libraries for image processing and optimizing.
Should I port my c libs to native client for publishing as chrome app?
Is there any other way to use the c libs?

Comment: Of course, the libraries themselves can't be published as Chrome Apps, but, assuming all the rules are followed, Chrome Apps using them can be. There's already a list of open source libraries ported to native client code (not sure how many, if any, are NaCl-only and how many are PNaCl), but by all means if your library of wide usefulness, go ahead and make it available.

Answer (score 1):

Native Client (NaCl), or Portable Native Client (PNaCl) are great options, this guide can help you [choose between NaCl and PNaCl](https://developers.google.com/native-client/pnacl-preview/nacl-and-pnacl). They will offer the best performance. Should you want to deploy to other browsers that don't support NaCl, you can investigate [pepper.js](https://github.com/google/pepper.js), and do your port with those additional constraints. That will enable you to use either [P]NaCl or [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten).